# NSView - Quick Look and NSResponder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicklook, nsresponder

I've subclassed NSView (MyCustomView) and have added it to my NSWindow's Content View in InterfaceBuilder using the custom view object in MainMenu.xib.

I have since added code to accept Quick Look responses to MyCustomView.

After calling this:

```
[[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Which asks the Quick Look window to appear, apparently the QLPreviewPanel goes through the Responder chain looking for anything that responds to -(BOOL)acceptsPreviewPanelControl: in order to do what it needs to. MyCustomView doesn't seem to be responding, despite having the relevant methods for Quick Look to function, including the aforementioned.

I tried adding the following to my init method of MyCustomView but makes no difference:

```
[self acceptsFirstResponder];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Any ideas what I am missing? I assume it's something to do with my xib setup?

Comment: The proper way to become first responder is [self.window makeFirstResponder:self];

Comment: OK, even with that though it still appears my subclassed NSView isn't in the responder chain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my issue. My NSView subclass did not implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```